# Trouble with breaking out of a while loop when inputting a Quantity

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a question. I am essentially done with my program except for one final break of the while loop I created. If I enter -1 to break out of my first output question "Enter Product Number (1-5) or -1 to Quit" it breaks out without an issue. If I enter -1 during the second question "Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit" it just loops back into the next Product Number request.

I have tried looking up some additional information on breaking out of while loops and have tried applying the same logic to my existing code. Unfortunately I still am having the same issue. It doesn't appear this particular request is a repeat question so I feel safe asking it. What in the heck am I doing wrong because after about an hour of trying to figure this out, I am just going bonkers. Any direction would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Prog

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModuleFour {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int pNumber = 0; //declaring integer for Product Number
    int pQuantity= 0; //declaring integer quantity of Product
    double totalcost = 0; //declaring double for Total Cost of combined Product
    double cost = 0; //declaring double for cost of each Product
        Scanner productTotal = new Scanner(System.in); //create scanner productTotal
        pNumber = 0;
        pQuantity = 0;
    while (pNumber >= 0 && pNumber <=5) //set condition of pNumber for while loop
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Product Number (1-5) or -1 to Quit"); //print out asking for input
        pQuantity = productTotal.nextInt(); //
    switch(pQuantity) { //begin switch statement
    case 1: //start of cases, all are the same. 
        System.out.println("Product " + (pNumber+1));
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
        pQuantity = productTotal.nextInt(); 
        cost = 2.98; //declare cost of case 1. Same method for each case. 
        totalcost = totalcost + cost*pQuantity; //setting totalcost algorithm.
        System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost); //print out the current totalcost.
        pNumber++; //increase value of pNumber by 1. Same for each case. 
    break; //break out of Case 1. Same for each case.
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Product " + (pNumber+1));
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
        pQuantity = productTotal.nextInt();
        cost = 4.50;
        totalcost = totalcost + cost*pQuantity;
        System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
        pNumber++;
    break;
    case 3:

        System.out.println("Product " + (pNumber+1));
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
        pQuantity = productTotal.nextInt();
        cost = 9.98;
        totalcost = totalcost + cost*pQuantity;
        System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
        pNumber++;
    break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Product " + (pNumber+1));
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
        pQuantity = productTotal.nextInt();
        cost = 4.49;
        totalcost = totalcost + cost*pQuantity;
        System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
        pNumber++;
    break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Product " + (pNumber+1));
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
        pQuantity = productTotal.nextInt();
        cost = 6.87;
        totalcost = totalcost + (cost*pQuantity);
        System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
        pNumber++;
    case -1: //declare case for -1 to break out of while loop
        ****pNumber = -1; //set condition for pNumber to break out of loop with input of -1.
        pQuantity = -1; //set condition for pQuantity to break out of loop with input of -1.****
    break; //when condition is met (-1 as input) break out of while loop.
    }
        System.out.println("Total cost-->" +totalcost); //print out the final total cost
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the  case -1 in the switch statement.  Instead you can add the condition of pQuantity > 1 into the while condition as below:

```
while ((pNumber >= 0 && pNumber <=5) || ( pQuantity >1))
```

Right now, if you enter -1 to the first question, it exited out of the program not because of the last case -1 condition, but because of the while loop condition.  But when you enter -1 to the second question ( the product quantity), it will go to the corresponding case condition, completes and break out of the switch statement and will go back to while loop.  It will not go to case -1 condition check.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response! So I added your recommendation into the while condition. When I input -1 into my first question, it breaks as before. If I enter -1 into my second question (with that portion of my Case-1 removed (and I tried with case -1 completely commented out) I still am required to enter -1 twice to completely break out of the while loop. I feel as though I am missing something still.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my previous answer.  The actual answer should be 
`while ((pNumber >= 0 && pNumber <=5) && ( pQuantity != -1 ))` instead of the previous answer, as you want to continue the loop only if pNumber is between 0 and 5 inclusive and pQuantity != -1

Comment: I actually figured it out as well! I was playing around with the code and realize, you know what, I don't have pQuantity by itself inside the Loop condition. Ended up getting 50/50 on my assignment which I am happy with. I just wish our professor would leave notations or some critiques telling me how I could improve my code.